# Кнопка срабатывает со второго клика, а должна с первого, как устранить?

Tags: javascript

Во внешнем файле функция:

```
var class;  
 function btn1(class) {  
    var elm = document.getElementById(class).style;

     elm.display=((elm.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none');
}
```

Данная функция вызывается в теге `div onClick="btn1('p1')`. По нажатии на кнопку должно открываться окно, при повторном - закрываться. Все работает, но при загрузке или обновлении страницы кнопка срабатывает только со второго раза, все последующие разы - с первого. Если прописать

```
onclick= "var elm = document.getElementById(class).style; elm.display=((elm.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none')";
```

непосредственно в теге без использования внешнего файла, то кнопка срабатывает с первого раза.

Теперь вопрос:
Возможно ли эту проблему исправить при использовании функции во внешнем файле, если да, то как? Или этот бок не исправим и все надо прописывать в документе?
Наглядный [результат](http://www.krezland.ru/index.php?page=poker/poker_school).

Comment: @Krezvaa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@Krezvaa, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: btn1 is not defined

`class` в `js` - это зарезервировано, и использовать это слово в качестве названия переменной приводит к ошибке.

[image]

Comment: Не знаю у меня работает все нормально без ошибок. И изменение имени переменной результата не дало.

Answer (score 0):

Была аналогичная ситуация.
Вынес `display:none` из файла css в основной файл и всё заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Напишите так:

```
elm.display=((elm.display == 'none' || elm.display == '') ? 'block' : 'none');
```

**UPD** Прошу прощения за неполный ответ.

Смысл в том, что document.getElementById("id").style представляет только inline стиль.  
Т.е. для

```
<div id="id" style="display:none">foo</div>
```

будет

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display=='none'
```

а для

```
<style>
  #id {display:none}
</style>
<div id="id">foo</div>
```

будет

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display==''
```

Таким образом, с точки зрения браузера элементы в обоих случаях будут спрятанными, но с точки зрения javascript и document.getElementById("id").style в частности стиль будет отличаться.

Соответственно, если вы присваиваете

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display=='block'
```

то это приводит к

```
<style>
  #id {display:none}/*тут как было, так и останется*/
</style>    
<div id="id" style="display:block">foo</div><!-- а здесь будет inline стиль, у которого приоритет выше, чем у того, который в stylesheet указан -->
```

Ну и теперь функция ваша будет работать с пустым значением style.display для первого клика, когда inline стиль пустой, а применен стиль из stylesheet'а. И при последующих кликах будет меняться уже inline стиль в зависимости от предыдущих указанных в нем значений.

как вариант можно еще написать

```
elm.display=((elm.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block');
```

Так еще лучше и короче.

**UPD2** Если есть желание не завязываться на знание того, что у вас в таблицах стилей прописано, то можно получить итоговый вычисленный стиль для элемента.

```
var elm = document.getElementById(id);
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elm,"");
elm.style.display = (style.display == 'none')?'block':'none';
```

тогда будет работать при любых заданных стилях, хоть в stylesheet, хоть в inline стиле.

Comment: Да такая запись помогла, но вот почему помогла я так и не понял. Если можно то прошу объяснить почему именно такая запись решила проблему?

Comment: Баги в коносли остались.

Comment: обновил ответ.

Comment: да ``var class`` уберите вообще, оно там не нужно. и в функции параметр переименуйте в ``id``, например, по смыслу больше подходит.